# Change Default first day of week for datepart in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to change the default first day of a week in a query in order to make Saturday the first day of the week.

Does anybody know how?

Comment: I would usually try to flip things around and write code that *doesn't depend on the `datefirst` setting that is in effect*. It'll stand you in good stead if/when you're writing e.g. a UDF and suddenly can't change the `datefirst` setting. (It also makes code *portable* when you're e.g. sharing it with people on here)

Comment: I can't change anything for now since it is an already written application and everywhere they are using Saturday as first day of the week that's why i need to set it in my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [DATEFIRST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql)

```
SET DATEFIRST 6; -- 6 is Saturday
```

Comment: does it change the datefirst for the current query or permanently? I want to change it for the current query only

Comment: permanent so at the end of the query change it back to `7` which is the default  setting.